# Gradle compiling java sources when they have not changed but classes modified by aopc

Tags: gradle, aop, jboss5.x

In my gradle project I compile my java sources to generated classes and then run a custom task to modify the classed using JBoss aopc to intrument the classes for cross-cutting features (aspects) such as performance monitoring etc.

For some odd reason, on a subsequent assemble task, this causes the java sources to be compiled even though none of their input java source files have changed. WHat has changed is the .class file for a few source files that were instrumented for aspects.

The gradle debug out says:

```
Executing task ':project1:compilePlafSrcJava' (up-to-date check took 1.998 secs) due to:
  Output file /pkg1/Class1.class has changed.
  Output file /pkg1/Class2.class has changed.
  Output file /pkg1/Class3.class has changed.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':project1:compilePlafSrcJava'.
```

Note the 3 classes are the ones that are instrumented by jboss aopc after being generated by javac.

It seems that if the timestamp on the classes is later than the timestamp on the corresponding .java file then recompilation should not be done. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are modifying the output of the compile task. Gradle detects that its outputs have been "tampered with" and will want to regenerate them. You have a couple of options.

1. Do the instrumentation inside a `doLast { }` block on the 'compileJava' task.
2. Copy the source to an intermediate directory then instrument it. You'll then need to update the 'jar' task to include this code.

Comment: Since the doLast{} (option 1) was much easier to do that's what I did and it worked like a charm. Thanks you. You are a life saver!!